# Disable "Generate Server/Client" inside Swagger Editor

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

After every start of Swagger Editor, the javascript api sends out two HTTP requests to

1. https://generator.swagger.io/api/gen/servers
2. https://generator.swagger.io/api/gen/clients

to render the navigation sections `Generate server` and `Generate clients`.

Because of only internal using, I doesn't need the functions for generating of server and client.

How to disable the requests and the rendering for both navigation sections?

**index.html**

```
  <script src="./dist/swagger-editor-bundle.js"> </script>
  <script src="./dist/swagger-editor-standalone-preset.js"> </script>
  <script src="./dist/spec.js"> </script>
  <script>
  window.onload = function() {
    const editor = SwaggerEditorBundle({
      spec: spec,
      dom_id: '#swagger-editor',
      layout: 'StandaloneLayout',
      presets: [
        SwaggerEditorStandalonePreset
      ]
    })

    window.editor = editor
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `swagger2GeneratorUrl: null` and `oas3GeneratorUrl: null` to the `SwaggerEditorBundle` initialization code:

```js
    const editor = SwaggerEditorBundle({
      spec: spec,
      dom_id: '#swagger-editor',
      layout: 'StandaloneLayout',
      presets: [
        SwaggerEditorStandalonePreset
      ],
      swagger2GeneratorUrl: null,  // <-----
      oas3GeneratorUrl: null       // <-----
    })
```